# Does $a_n = \cos\left(n\ln \left(1+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I want to check if a sequence converges or diverges. The sequence is the following:

$$a_n = \cos\left(n\ln \left(1+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)$$

I though of maybe using sandwich theorem, but can I use it, saying that the value will lie between $-1$ and $1$? If not, can anyone point me to where I should be looking at.

Comment: Consider the Taylor expansion of $\ln (1 + x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}a_n &= \cos \left(n \ln \left( 1+ \frac \pi n\right) \right)\\
&=\cos\left(\ln\left(1+\frac\pi n\right)^n\right)
\end{align}$$

You may recognize that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac x n\right)^n = e^x$$ for all $x$ (this being one way to define the exponential function).

Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac \pi n\right)^n = e^\pi$.

Since $\ln$ is continuous throughout its domain, which includes $e^\pi$, and $\cos$ is continuous everywhere, your sequence will approach $\cos(\ln e^\pi)=\cos \pi = -1$.

Thanks for the tip on continuity from davin.

Comment: Did you see davin's answer?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Not until I posted mine. I recognize they are exactly the same idea, written somewhat differently. I considered deleting mine, but I think the asker may perhaps be more likely to recognize the identity in the form I have given, so I left it as is.

Comment: Your answer is a little more detailed, though.

Comment: Both fail to mention the key word "continuity"

Comment: @davin: Fixed now.

Comment: Could you tell me why can we change `n` to a power?

Comment: @aizen92: that's a general property of logarithms: $a\log b = \log (b^a)$.

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks

Answer (score 4):

$$
a_n = \cos\left(n\ln \left(1+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right) = \cos\ln \left(\left(1+\frac 1{n/\pi}\right)^{n /\pi}\right)^\pi \to \cos\ln e^\pi = -1
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that near the origin $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^2)$$

so that $$ n\log \left(1+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)={\pi}-\frac{\pi^2}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

It follows that the inner sequence goes to $\pi$ as $n\to\infty$ so the whole thing goes to $\cos \pi=-1$